# how to use ".contains" for an object array in swift 3.0

Tags: arrays, swift3, contain

How to use contains in case if needs to get a particular object array contains an object.

Trying to select and deselect checkbox ( using 2 images ) for tableview rows.

Code :

```
var originalParams = [ParamsModel]()
var selectedParams = [ParamsModel]()
if selectedParams.contains(originalParams[indexPath.index]) {
            cell.btnSelect.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"checked.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        else
        {
            cell.btnSelect.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"unchecked.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
```

I'm using swift 3.0 .it shows compiler error "Missing argument label 'where' in call". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking? This is really unclear.

Comment: Does this work as you would like: `selectedcheckboxArray.contains(checkboxArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))`?

Comment: By the way, don't use "Array" in the names of variables. Simply make it plural, and the array is implied. For example `selectedCheckboxes` instead of `selectedcheckboxArray`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov . exactly this selectedcheckboxArray.contains(checkboxArray.objectAtIndex(i‌​ndexPath.row)) was I tried but objectAtIndex doesn't exist for an array. any other method which I can use?

Comment: Oh of course, just subscript the array: `checkboxArray[indexPath.row]`. Of course, it should be a Swift type, and not NSArray

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov made the question bit more clear. Yes, as you have mentioned should not use Array ie Hungarian notation in variables. Will definitely change that too. thanks

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I tried subscripting as you mentioned but it shows error about the "missing argument variable label where in call". Not sure what it is

Comment: Update your question with your most recent code, including the declarations of all referenced values

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov updated the code in the question and added  the compiler error too.

Comment: Read my last comment again, carefully

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov sorry , added declaration too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129313/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-user2695433).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParamsModel` needs to conform to `Equatable` if you want to be able to call `contains(_:)` on an Array of `ParamsModel` instances.

This code can also be written more succinctly as:

```
let imageName = selectedParams.contains(originalParams[indexPath.index]) ? "checked.png" : "unchecked.png"
cell.btnSelect.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: imageName), for: .normal)
```

Comment: Thanks . I have made the model class to conform to Equatable class ParamsModel : Equatable{
    
    //Mark: Properties
    var param : String
    var isSelected : Bool
    
    //Mark: Instantiation
    init( param: String, isSelected: Bool ){
        
        self.param = param
        self.isSelected = isSelected
        
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: ParamsModel, rhs: ParamsModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.param == rhs.param
    }

} But now the error in contains is "cannot subscript a value of type ParamsModel to an index of type '_' "

Comment: That sounds like a new question :p

Comment: I ll rather add it as a new question :P